# jquery autocomplete with php foreach generated results

Tags: php, jquery, image, autocomplete, foreach

I have been trying for days to get jquery autocomplete to work the way I need it to.

so far I have this which works fine:

```
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [<?php 

$taglist = Array();
  foreach ($users as $user) 
    if ($user->getAttribute('first_name') == ''){
       $taglist[] = '"'.$user->getUserName().'"';
}else{
       $taglist[] = '"'.$user->getAttribute('first_name').' '.$user->getAttribute('last_name').'"';
}

echo join(',', $taglist); 

?>];

$("#searchmem").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) { 
        $("#searchmem").val(ui.item.label);
        $("#submit").click(); 
    }
}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li />")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<a><img src='/files/avatars/1.jpg' />" + item.label + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
    }
});
</script>
```

This will output the image /files/avatars/1.jpg next to the respective users username or full name.

The problem I'm having is trying to output the right users avatar. Each .jpg file corresponds with the username so I could have used $user->getUserID() in the src but this won't work because it's not inside the foreach $users as $user loop.

I have tried putting the whole autocomplete script inside the foreach which when tested did alert the right thing but autocomplete wouldn't work.

I have also tried creating two variables such as

availableTags1 = { label: .... $user->getUserName() etc... }

availableTags2 = { avatar: .... $user->getUserID() etc... }

availableTags = availableTags1 + availableTags2;

and

```
.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li />")
    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
    .append("<a><img src=' + item.avatar + ' />" + item.label + "</a>")
    .appendTo(ul);
}
```

But again this didn't work. I'm completely lost! How can I get it to output the image alongside the relevant username? Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you have to build an array like :

```
var availableTags = [
    {label: '...', avatar: '...'},
    {label: '...', avatar: '...'},
    ...
];
```

And use:

```
.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li />")
    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
    .append("<a><img src='" + item.avatar + "' />" + item.label + "</a>") // Note the additional double quotes
    .appendTo(ul);
}
```

(see this example on [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) for using custom data)

Then, for generating you array via PHP, you should use:

```
<?php
$taglist = Array();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $data = array();
    if ($user->getAttribute('first_name') == ''){
        $data["label"] = $user->getUserName();
    } else {
        $data["label"] = $user->getAttribute('first_name').' '.$user->getAttribute('last_name');
    }
    $data["avatar"] = $user->getUserID();
    $taglist[] = $data;
}
?>
var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($taglist); ?>;
```