# Is it possible to launch/open a Bootstrap Modal with jQuery UI Autocomplete Select event or custom event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have PHP/MySQL AJAX source for my Autocomplete field. It works great, per the [jQuery autocomplete remote source docs](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote)

The remote source docs allows an array of data so I can pass the labels var for the dropdown results and I have the ID in the array. ([here is an example of a similar setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792661/jquery-autocomplete-with-php-foreach-generated-results))

So feeling confident the server side data is good,  I want to open a Modal on select from the list of options. The Select event needs to pass an ID to load the data in the modal. Is this possible?

My modal is opened with a class selector on click function. It reference a data-id.

```
<a name="views" class="leadview"  data-task-id="179">Task 179 - user 1458</a>
```

So I assume triggering a modal must happen with the Select or Focus event?

```
$( " Some Selector? " ).on( "autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

I'm really stuck connecting the autocomplete to the modal with an ID, it's my first time using autocomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume the you want to display a bootstrap modal when user select an option listed in autocomplet ...
if so  then use :

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  select: function( event, ui ) {
         var taskid = $(this).data("task-id");
          $('#myModal').modal('show');   
          $('#myModal .header').html(taskid);
 }
});
```